# constructing grammar for 1*0*1(1+0)*

Tags: automata, regular-language, linear-regression, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I want to construct a grammar for the following regular expression: $1^*0^*1(1+0)^*$. I did it the following way:

$S \rightarrow AB1C$

$A \rightarrow 1A | \epsilon$

$B \rightarrow 0B | \epsilon$

$C \rightarrow 0C|1C| \epsilon$

Is it correct?

Comment: Well, almost, the last line should be $C\to 0C\,|\,1C\,|\,\epsilon$.

Comment: right, I just forgot that.

Comment: @Berci I have posted another question if you d like to help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4397537/constructing-grammar-for-aibj-i-j